# Flipping inputs in multilabel classification

Tags: classification, precision-recall, metric, multilabel

I have framed a classification problem as follows:

I have $N$ items, and wish to predict a set of relevant tags for each out of $M$ tags. An item can have anywhere from 0 to $M$ applicable tags.

To use `sklearn.metrics` to measure a model's performance on this task, for every item I use a multi-hot encoding of it's predicted and actual relevant tags; an array $[t_1, ..., t_M]$ where $t_i$ indicated whether the $i$th tag applies to an item.

When calculating metrics like precision or recall (or others), `sklearn` will aggregate TN, TP, FN, FP for each tag, then average or directly output the results.

But what if I decided to reframe the problem as:

I have $M$ tags, and wish to predict a set of relevant items for each out of $N$ items. A tag can be assigned to anywhere from 0 to $N$ items.

Now, despite calculating metrics such as weighted / unweighted average precision and recall on the exact same data as before, I get different results. I am really having a lot of trouble wrapping my head around what has changed. Is there a superior amongst these two approaches, and under what circumstances?

For the first approach there's also the option of calculating the precision / recall / etc. of tag assignment to each item, then averaging the scores across all times. Is this better? Worse? Completely different?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: "I have M tags, and wish to predict a set of relevant items for each out of N items." Is this a helpful formulation? Wouldn't you want to be able to assign relevant tags to an particular item separately from any other items you might or might not have?

Comment: @dipetkov certainly, but with it I would be able to find out which items were being classified poorly.